# How to substitute integral operators into polynomials?

Tags: replacement, polynomials, operators

Suppose I have a polynomial

$a_0+a_1 f(x,t) + a_2 f(x,t)^2 + ....$.

In code,

```
a0 + a1 y + a2 y^2 + a3 y^3 /. y :> Integrate[Subscript[y, k] E^(I k y), k]
```

> ```
> a0 + 
> a1 Integrate[E^(I k y) Subscript[y, k], k] + 
> a2 Integrate[E^(I k y) Subscript[y, k], k]^2 + 
> a3 Integrate[E^(I k y) Subscript[y, k], k]^3
> ```

I want to replace $f$ with $\int f_k(t) e^{ik x}dk$. 
The problem that I am facing is that when I use the replace rule, I get

$\qquad a_0+a_1 \int f_k(t) e^{ikx}dk + a_2 (\int f_k(t) e^{ikx}dk)^2 + ....$

on and on. Is there a way to sort integration variable such that I get

$\qquad a_0+a_1 \int f_{k_1}(t) e^{ik_1x}dk_1 + a_2 (\int f_{k_1}(t) e^{i{k_1}x}dk_1)(\int f_{k_2}(t) e^{i{k_2}x}dk_2) + ...$

automatically? Assume I can't fiddle with the code to generate these polynomials. Similarly let's say I have collected 3rd order terms which would look like

$\qquad \sum_i\hat L_i[f(x,t)]\hat K_i[f(x,t)]\hat T_i[f(x,t)],$

where $\hat L, \hat K , \hat T$ are some operators. Is there also ways to plug in the Fourier transformation of f so that the integration variables are automatically sorted?

Comment: Posts without proper example code (that is copypastable) tend to be frowned upon. Please edit your question and add appropriate code examples.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: You should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://wolfr.am/vxtW3QtE) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [`DownValues`](https://wolfr.am/vxtQt6LX) to the operator `Subscript` and not an `OwnValues` to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://wolfr.am/vxtT6JDX)

Comment: @rhermans Not to mention it makes the code very hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching can help here.

```
a0 + a1 y + a2 y^2 + a3 y^3 /. 
{a_ y :> 
   a Integrate[Subscript[y, Subscript[k, 1]] E^(I Subscript[k, 1] y), Subscript[k, 1]], 
 a_ y^n_ :> 
   a Times @@ Table[Integrate[Subscript[y, Subscript[k, sub]] E^(I Subscript[ k, sub] y), Subscript[k, sub]], {sub, 1, n}]}
```

> $\text{a0}+\text{a1} \int e^{i k_1 y} y_{k_1} \, dk_1+\text{a2} \left(\int e^{i k_1 y} y_{k_1} \, dk_1\right) \int e^{i k_2 y}
>    y_{k_2} \, dk_2+\text{a3} \left(\int e^{i k_1 y} y_{k_1} \, dk_1\right) \left(\int e^{i k_2 y} y_{k_2} \, dk_2\right) \int e^{i
>    k_3 y} y_{k_3} \, dk_3$